# Ruby Active Record returns relation in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have this code

```
@devices_data=Hash.new
@devices.each do |device|
 @devices_data[device.id.to_s] = @project.vibration_data.find(:all, conditions: { vibration_device_id: device.id })
end
```

But when I want to get data displayed in my view use following code:

```
<p><%= @devices_data %></p> //this show whole block of data
<p><%= @devices_data.first.id%></p> // it says undefined method `id' for # Array:0x000000058b0150
```

If I remove the hash container,just store data like(without define `@device_data=Hash.new`)

```
@devices.each do |device|
     @devices_data = @project.vibration_data.find(:all, conditions: { vibration_device_id: device.id})
 end
```

`<p><%= @devices_data.first.id%></p>`  will display its id instead of error message.
But I have more than 1 data in each device, I do need an array or hash to hold this. But this give me problem.I tried add `.first` to make code as

```
@devices_data[device.id.to_s] = @project.vibration_data.find(:all, conditions: { vibration_device_id: device.id }).first
```

and I have also tried change find to where to retrieve data.

```
@devices_data[device.id.to_s] = @project.vibration_data.where(vibration_device_id: device.id ).first
```

But they doesn't work, in view still return me relation instead of value,which give me an error message.

Whats my problem? How can I solve it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<p><%= @devices_data.first.id%></p> // it says undefined method `id' for # Array:0x000000058b0150
```

gives you an error because @devises_data.first will bring back the first item of the hash as an array of [key, value]

if you try

```
<p><%= @devices_data.first.last.id%></p>
```

will print the id you are looking for, because @devised_data is a hash, first will give you the first element of the hash as an array of [key, value], when you send to the array the message last will give you back the value object, and then with id you will be getting the id you are looking for

Comment: ya,seems like I need one more layer to get the data

Answer (score 0):

`.find(:all, :conditions => <cond>)` is an old way of finding a set of active records. you should now use `where(cond)` instead, and it should work better for you.

`where` returns an Active Relation... which you can then use a final method on to fetch either `all` or just the `first` item matching your conditions.

when you then apply `first` it will pull the first item out of the active relation for you - which seems to be what you want.

... but then, because you are storing this value into a hash... you then have to either iterate through all the items in the hash using `each`, or use `first` again to fetch out the first item that you have put into the hash...

so something like:

```
@devices_data = {}
@devices.each do |device|
 @devices_data[device.id.to_s] = @project.vibration_data.where( vibration_device_id: device.id ).first
end


<% @devices_data.each do |device_id, device| %>
   <p><%= device_id %></p>
   <p><%= device.name %></p> <!-- or whatever -->
<% end %>
```